# Some parts of external CSS are not loading

Tags: html, css

I have some external CSS file with this class defined

```
.abilityButton { 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Then I have the same class defined in the main file, with some properties, that I need to define dynamically by php. Looks like this:

```
.abilityButton { 
    width: ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.92)."px;
    height: ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.92)."px;
    border-top: solid ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.04)."px lightgrey;
    border-left: solid ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.04)."px lightgrey;
    border-bottom: solid ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.04)."px darkgrey;
    border-right: solid ".(($inner_cell_space/4) * 0.04)."px darkgrey;
}
```

My problem is in the external file, where only those 3 background properties work. Other simply disappear and are not shown in the browser development tool.They are obviously also not applied and i do not understand the problem.

I am convinced that there is nothing that could possibly override them directly, so I have no idea how to explain this behaviour.

What I need is to explain, why are properties in the external file discarted and how to prevent it.

**EDIT 1**

MS Edge renders the page correctly. So the problem is probably i chrome itself.
ctrl + shift + r doesnt work.
Inspecting the element result: Chrome now says that the source CSS does contain the properties (but they are not applied)

Comment: Can you upload and share the URL of your current code.

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: Okay, I found out, that in MS Edge it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the css rules aren't showing up in the inspector, it's probably either caching, or you're editing the wrong file/not uploading the file after making changes.

Have you tried doing a hard-refresh using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>? The external css file might be cached by your browser. Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but it has happened to me more often than I'd like to admit.

Comment: I have already tried this hard refresh. Didnt help. I also made sure that I am loading the right file. There is no other external file anyway. There is also another class, which loads well, but it has only one property (background-color)

Comment: Okay, I tried the hard refresh again and it started working. I have no idea what changed. I hope it stays functional from now on :D Looks like it really was the caching problem, but some strange kind...

Comment: Yeah, that happens to me all the time. If you're working on a server hosted by some company, they might have server-sided caching enabled. Glad I could help!

Comment: You were probably right with that cache theory. What was the problem here was that the hard refresh did not clear the cached CSS file. I had to delete all cached files and pictures manually in the settings. Then everything worked well.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember is that the stylesheets are cascading. It's possible they are being overwritten elsewhere.

You should use element inspector in your browser to target elements which should have styles, and scroll down the sidebar to see if they are being applied, but are being overwritten by something else.

Sometimes a fix for this is just being more specific in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I used the inspector from chrome, but it does not show the styles anyway, as it usually does even when they are overwritten. They are shown and cancelled by a line and are little transparent.